# Custom Print Dialog in c# .net 2.0

Tags: c#, printing

I need to create a print dialog. However, on that print dialog, i just want to hide some printers. I have read some article about customprintdialog like:

http://www.abstraction.net/content/articles/windowsforms-customprintdialog.htm

However, i still cannot find out the way to get the list of printer on that print dialog.
The dialog looks like:
[image]

Following the code in the link above, There is a GetDlgItem function from user32.dll library, that can help me to get a control from the dialog (Ok button's id is 1, Cancel button's id is 2):

```
private const int IDOK = 1;
private const int IDCANCEL = 2;
```

But i don't know the combobox's id (that contains list of printer) so i cannot edit that combobox. I have tried with some id like 3, 4.... but there is no item with these id.

Does anyone know how to customize the list of printer in this case, please help me :)
If you have another solution for my problem that different with the one in my provied link, also let me know.

Comment: Is your problem, create a custom print dialog or retrieve installed printer list?

Comment: I need to create a custom print dialog that just list some printers not all of installed printer. The problem's not retrieving installed printer list.

Comment: Use Spy++ to find the ID.

Comment: I´m still don't understand, are you trying to modify the default printer dialog to hide some printers? or are you trying to build a print dialog from scratch in C# hidden some installed printers?

Comment: @RicardoMomm : I'm trying to modify the default printer dialog to hide some printers :)

Comment: @HansPassant : by Spy++, I have found what i need :) thanks a lot.