# how to customize ReportViewer printDialog for selected printers only

Tags: c#, reporting-services, window, ssrs-2008

i am using below code to call my SSRS report on window form.

```
 reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
                reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
                reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = textBox2.Text;
                reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Now afters reports load,on print dialog it shows all the printers list. but client requirement is to show only few printers in select printer list.

[image]

how can i do this using c#?

Comment: You could set default printer settings via [ReportViewer.PrinterSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.printersettings.aspx) property on the `ReportViewer` object. These are then used to initialize the Print dialog; not sure if you can go on to restrict what printers are shown however. To remove and/or hide them would mean they are uninstalled surely?

Comment: its not working, i have already tried this,

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static ArrayList GetPrinters()
    {
        ArrayList ArrayPrinters = new ArrayList();

        PrintDocument prtdoc = new PrintDocument();
        //prt.PrinterSettings.PrinterName returns the name of the Default Printer
        string strDefaultPrinter = prtdoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

        //this will loop through all the Installed printers and add the Printer Names to a ComboBox.
        foreach (String strPrinter in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
        {
            //This will insert the Default Printer Name matches with the current Printer Name returned by for loop
            if (strPrinter.CompareTo(strDefaultPrinter) == 0)
            {
                ArrayPrinters.Insert(0, strPrinter);
            }
            else
            {
                ArrayPrinters.Add(strPrinter);
            }
        }
        return ArrayPrinters;
    }
```

Comment: or use Combobox to fill Papersize,Orientation,PaperSize

  PrintSettings.SetPaperSize(document, cmbPaperSize1.Text, PaperOrientation.Portrait, cmbPrinter.Text);

Comment: No, i want to show only limited printer names in list., I don't want to change other settings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330261/custom-print-dialog-in-c-sharp-net-2-0